# Efficient data cleaning - MsExcel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have Ms Excel spreadsheet with 2400 companies.
It now looks like -

```
Autumn Ridge Golf Course, Inc.
11420 Auburn Road
Fort Wayne, IN 46845
(260) 637-8727


All Occasion Party Rental
4620 Speedway Drive
Fort Wayne, IN 46825
(260) 484-3964
```

..... etc.

My goal is to make it into friendly table format:

```
Autumn Ridge Golf Course  11420 Auburn Road    Fort Wayne IN 46845 (260)637-8727
All Occasion Party Rental 4620 Speedway Drive  Fort Wayne IN 46825 (260)484-3964
```

I know "copy"/"paste special" "Transpose" excel option; but it'll be quite slow...
to do with 2400 companies.

Is there are any faster way to do it?
I need any possible way to transform my data into table-like(horizontal) view

Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using VBA to store the data in an array, and then write out to a new worksheet.

I assume that blank lines will be between all sets of data and there are no blank lines *within* any particular set of data.

```
Sub HorizontalSplit()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim c As Long: c = 0
Dim r As Long: r = 1
Dim addressInfo() As Variant


Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as needed`
Set sh2 = Worksheets.Add(After:=sh1) 'Modify as needed, set to an existing sheet, etc.`

With sh1
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A2500") 'Modify as needed to fit your range of address info`
    For Each cl In rng

        If cl.Value = vbNullString Then
        'write out the data (if any), or skip the cell if there is no data in the array`
            If UBound(addressInfo) > 0 Then
                For c = 0 To UBound(addressInfo)
                    sh2.Cells(r, c + 1).Value = addressInfo(c)
                Next

                c = -1
                'clear out our array for the next brand'
                Erase addressInfo
                ReDim addressInfo(0)
                r = r + 1
            End If
        Else:
            'Add this row of data to the array
            c = c + 1
            ReDim Preserve addressInfo(c)
            addressInfo(c) = cl.Value

        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 `THANK YOU !!! THANK YOU !!!! – Hell_77 2 hours ago` for making someone really really happy :)

Comment: @Hell_77 You're quite welcome! If it works, please consider marking the answer as "accepted" so that others can refer to this solution for similar problems in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

If your data is formatted exactly as you specify, there might be a quick and easy non-Excel approach.

1. Copy your data into a decent text editor (such as Notepad++: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)
2. Do a Find/Replace using a Search Mode of "Extended" and replace all instances of multiple blank lines with some special character.  (e.g. if you have one blank like between addresses, do a find for **\r\n\r\n** and replace with **|**.)
3. Do a Find/Replace for the remaining blank lines, and replace with a tab.  (Again in Extended mode, do a find for **\r\n** and replace with **\t**)
4. Do a Find/Replace for your special character with new lines again.  (In Extended mode, find **|** and replace with **\r\n**)
5. Copy and paste the resulting text into Excel.  Any additional cleanup should be within the realm of Excel formulas.

If you are against or unable to download additional software (although I highly recommend Notepad++), you should be able to accomplish something similar with MS Word.  The documentation at http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/find-and-replace-text-or-other-items-HA001230392.aspx#_Toc282602054 seems to be along the lines of what I remember where **^p** is used to find paragraph marks (new lines) and **^t** is used to find tabs.